# Youtube Audience Retention API

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way to get YouTube audience retention data of a particular video via API? This doesn't seem to be available via API (even in youtube experimental API). Any other way, like parsing the UI data or contacting Youtube to get this data?

Or any idea whether this data will be available via API in near future?

Answer (score 2):

It's a common feature request that we've heard from developers, and there's a good chance that it will be added. I don't have any specific details to share about when that might happen, though.

Your best bet is to file a formal [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request%29) and we'll track things there.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! 

I will add a feature request.